# Regex to extract a value in a string of parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the value stored in a cookie on my site.
From "document.cookie", I get the following string :

```
startBAK=R3415751377; _ga=GA1.2.1180519210.1552400330; _gid=GA1.2.1693387126.1552400330; trkPV=4; ata=google.com;
```

I want to extract the value of **ata**  **"google.com"**
So I tried this :

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
var regex = /(?:ata=)(.*?);/g;
var value = cookie.match(regex);
return value
```

The result is **"ata=google.com"**.... how can i get the value only : **"google.com"** ?

Comment: try this on your third line: var value = cookie.match(regex).split("=")[1];
Edit: to explain, you need to have the ata= part in the regex, or else it can't find the match. After that, then you can get just the section you want.

Comment: Use `var value = regex.exec( cookie );` Then value will be the array `["ata=google....", "google.com"]`. If a second `ata=` is found inside the string, it'll be at index 2.

Comment: @EthanGreen It's almost that... the result is ""google.com;"... how can I remove the ";" at the end ?

Comment: @B4b4j1 best bet would be substring. I like to split it up in two lines to be easier to read. so new line would be value = value.substr(0,value.length-1); which will truncate the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/exec) method:

```
const value = (/(?:ata=)(.*?);/g).exec(cookie)[1]
```

Comment: It's working fine.. result is "google.com".
Thanks